# reassigning std::unique_ptr<QAudioBuffer> member causes heap corruption

Tags: qt, c++11, lambda, smart-pointers, qtmultimedia

I am having problems trying to construct a smart pointer member to a `std::unique_ptr<QAudioBuffer>`.

This is assigned in a button click QT slot as follows:

```
void
MainWindow::on_start_clicked() {
    // second time this occurs HEAP corruption inside createAudioBuffer function
    mpAudioBuffer = createAudioBuffer(*mpAudioConfig);
    ...
}
```

The construction of the `QAudioBuffer` smart pointer works fine the first time it is assigned, however when this is reassigned (via a member fn `createAudioBuffer`) due to a change in the `AudioConfig` parameter that causes a `sizeInBytes` change, then the `std::make_unique<QAudioBuffer>(...)` crashes resulting in a HEAP_CORRUPTION_DETECTED popup dialog in visual studio.

This crash is in the array deleter corresponding to the heap allocated `const auto data = std::make_unique<char[]>(sizeInBytes)`  This heap allocated smart pointer array is passed along with a length parameter to QByteArray where is should be deep copied, however the crash would appear to point to some double delete somewhere.

```
std::unique_ptr<QAudioBuffer>
MainWindow::createAudioBuffer(const AudioConfig& rConfig) const
{
    const auto bytesPerSample =
        (rConfig.sampleFormat == SampleFormat::Uint8) ? 1 :
        (rConfig.sampleFormat == SampleFormat::Int32) ? 4 :
        (rConfig.sampleFormat == SampleFormat::Int16) ? 2 : -1;
    const auto sizeInBytes = bytesPerSample * rConfig.channelCount * rConfig.frameCount;
    // allocate raw data for the QByteArray which is passed into the QAudioBuffer ctor.
    const auto data = std::make_unique<char[]>(sizeInBytes);
    // TODO initialize data here
    return std::make_unique<QAudioBuffer>(QByteArray(
        data.get(), sizeInBytes), [&rConfig]()-> QAudioFormat {
            // use lambda to initialize member - no need for separate
            // QAudioFormat object as embedded into test QAudioBuffer
            QAudioFormat format;
            format.setSampleRate(static_cast<int>(rConfig.sampleRate));
            format.setChannelCount(static_cast<int>(rConfig.channelCount));
            format.setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat::Int32);
            return format;
        }());
}
```

The corresponding stack trace is as follows:

```
ucrtbased.dll!free_dbg_nolock(void * const block, const int block_use) Line 952 C++
ucrtbased.dll!_free_dbg(void * block, int block_use) Line 1030  C++
afdx.exe!operator delete(void * block) Line 38  C++
afdx.exe!operator delete[](void * block) Line 32    C++
afdx.exe!std::default_delete<char [0]>::operator()<char,0>(char * _Ptr) Line 3156   C++
afdx.exe!std::unique_ptr<char [0],std::default_delete<char [0]>>::~unique_ptr<char [0],std::default_delete<char [0]>>() Line 3390   C++
afdx.exe!MainWindow::createAudioBuffer(const AudioConfig & rConfig) Line 544    C++
```

Comment: Please show how the buffer is originally created. BTW, in this particular example there's no need to even create `data`, `QByteArray` of given size can be created right away. If that's not the case and some computations are going on in-between - they might be relevant. Either way, please show more code.

Comment: @alagner I left out a for loop that initializes the data array.  The idea is that the QAudioBuffer could be created with a preshaped waveform of typically a sine wave of pcm audio, I didn't want to muddy the waters wih these details. The place where it breaks is if I create a  4k buffer (1024 frames - 32 bits/sample) - this works fine - followed  by a 2k buffer (1024 frames - 16 bits/sample) - this crashes.

Comment: You say "when this is reassigned (via a member fn `createAudioBuffer`)" but I don't see where `createAudioBuffer` assigns or reassigns any data member of any class. What exactly is being reassigned where?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I clarified the question - see where the assignment occurs in a button click event.